# how to split each row in the dataframe which has many batches and print out different rows for each batch

Tags: python, pandas, split

I convert csv file into data frame.  I need to split each row in the data frame into different rows depending on the number of batches present in a single row.

Here is the input 
I am including only 2 rows

```
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-21-11,00:00:00,REGULAR,003169391,001097585,05-21-11,04:00:00,REGULAR,003169415,001097588,05-21-11,08:00:00,REGULAR,003169431,001097607,05-21-11,12:00:00,REGULAR,003169506,001097686,05-21-11,16:00:00,REGULAR,003169693,001097734,05-21-11,20:00:00,REGULAR,003169998,001097769,05-22-11,00:00:00,REGULAR,003170119,001097792,05-22-11,04:00:00,REGULAR,003170146,001097801              
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-22-11,08:00:00,REGULAR,003170164,001097820,05-22-11,12:00:00,REGULAR,003170240,001097867,05-22-11,16:00:00,REGULAR,003170388,001097912,05-22-11,20:00:00,REGULAR,003170611,001097941,05-23-11,00:00:00,REGULAR,003170695,001097964,05-23-11,04:00:00,REGULAR,003170701,001097964,05-23-11,08:00:00,REGULAR,003170746,001098069,05-23-11,12:00:00,REGULAR,003170897,001098378
```

Comment: Are there some csv header?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you provide expected output?

Answer (score 1):

## setup

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """A002,R051,02-00-00,05-21-11,00:00:00,REGULAR,003169391,001097585,05-21-11,04:00:00,REGULAR,003169415,001097588,05-21-11,08:00:00,REGULAR,003169431,001097607,05-21-11,12:00:00,REGULAR,003169506,001097686,05-21-11,16:00:00,REGULAR,003169693,001097734,05-21-11,20:00:00,REGULAR,003169998,001097769,05-22-11,00:00:00,REGULAR,003170119,001097792,05-22-11,04:00:00,REGULAR,003170146,001097801              
A002,R051,02-00-00,05-22-11,08:00:00,REGULAR,003170164,001097820,05-22-11,12:00:00,REGULAR,003170240,001097867,05-22-11,16:00:00,REGULAR,003170388,001097912,05-22-11,20:00:00,REGULAR,003170611,001097941,05-23-11,00:00:00,REGULAR,003170695,001097964,05-23-11,04:00:00,REGULAR,003170701,001097964,05-23-11,08:00:00,REGULAR,003170746,001098069,05-23-11,12:00:00,REGULAR,003170897,001098378   
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), header=None, index_col=[0, 1, 2])
```

## `pandas`

use `%` + `//` + `stack`

```
idx = pd.RangeIndex(len(df.columns))
df.columns = [idx % 5, idx // 5]
df.stack().rename_axis([None] * 4)

                             0         1        2        3        4
A002 R051 02-00-00 0  05-21-11  00:00:00  REGULAR  3169391  1097585
                   1  05-21-11  04:00:00  REGULAR  3169415  1097588
                   2  05-21-11  08:00:00  REGULAR  3169431  1097607
                   3  05-21-11  12:00:00  REGULAR  3169506  1097686
                   4  05-21-11  16:00:00  REGULAR  3169693  1097734
                   5  05-21-11  20:00:00  REGULAR  3169998  1097769
                   6  05-22-11  00:00:00  REGULAR  3170119  1097792
                   7  05-22-11  04:00:00  REGULAR  3170146  1097801
                   0  05-22-11  08:00:00  REGULAR  3170164  1097820
                   1  05-22-11  12:00:00  REGULAR  3170240  1097867
                   2  05-22-11  16:00:00  REGULAR  3170388  1097912
                   3  05-22-11  20:00:00  REGULAR  3170611  1097941
                   4  05-23-11  00:00:00  REGULAR  3170695  1097964
                   5  05-23-11  04:00:00  REGULAR  3170701  1097964
                   6  05-23-11  08:00:00  REGULAR  3170746  1098069
                   7  05-23-11  12:00:00  REGULAR  3170897  1098378
```